# C и C++. Pointer(int*) to int

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Вот [код](https://ideone.com/mQBckC) в C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a;
int* b;

int main()
{
    int d = 5;
    b = &d;
    a = (int)b;
    return 0;
}
```

И вот тот же [код](https://ideone.com/gaAzhm) в C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
int* b;

int main()
{
    int d = 7;
    b = &d;
    a = (int)b;
}
```

> Почему тот же самый код работает в C и не работает в C++.
>   И как в C происходит преобразование **int* to int**

Comment: Всякий указатель - адрес в памяти. Адрес - число, так вот и происходит...
PS. И приведенный код в плюсах (Visual Studio) работает

Comment: По ссылке размер int* больше, чем размер int, поэтому и не компилируется. Если поменять на больший тип, то соберется. Также имеется тип intptr_t/uintptr_t, размер которого может вместить значение из указателя. И да, C и C++ - разные языки. В C это собирается, потому что C считает, что программист знает что делает, если же программист болван, то компилятор не при чем.

Comment: @Croessmah размер int* скорее всего зависит от разрядности. Для 32-битной программы в студии sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов причем здесь студия? ТС привел ссылки на ideone, где это не так. Ну и в VS можете поставить сборку под x64.

Comment: @Croessmah можете написать как ответ

Comment: "Почему тот же самый код работает в C и не работает в C++." - откуда вообще возник такой вопрос? С и С++ - два совершенно разных языка. Почему вас удивляет, что "тот же самый код" воспринимается по разному трансляторами этих языков?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов В плюсах указатель это не адрес и не число (хотя и конвертируется в него).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, что означает фраза "указатель это не адрес"?

Comment: @wololo Что это разные весщи

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, но ведь указатель представляет некоторый адрес в памяти...

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, т.е. значение указателя - некоторый адрес в памяти.

Comment: @wololo указатель *представляет* адрес объекта, но это не тоже самое, что адресное пространство процесса. Т.е. вы не можете присвоить указателю какой-то произвольный адрес и записать через него значение по этому адресу в памяти.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Либо вы не правы, либо в Студии какие-то свои плюсы...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

И в С, и в С++ результирующее значение преобразования указательного типа к целочисленному определяется реализацией. Однако:

- В языке С++ преобразование указательного типа в целочисленный тип делается в соответствии со спецификацией `reinterpret_cast`. Спецификация `reinterpret_cast` явным образом говорит, что преобразование указательного типа в целочисленный тип допускается только если целочисленный тип обладает достаточным размером, для того, чтобы хранить результирующее значение. В вашем случае, очевидно, получилось так, что тип `int` не в состоянии хранить результат преобразования указателя типа `int *` к целочисленному типу. Поэтому код ошибочен.
- В языке С преобразование указательного типа в целочисленный тип не требует того, чтобы целочисленный тип был достаточно большим. Спецификация языка лишь говорит, что в случае недостаточного размера целочисленного типа *поведение не определено*.

Если предположить, что ваши С++ и С платформы обладают одинаковыми характеристиками типов `int *` и `int` и тип `int` слишком узок для хранения результата данного преобразования, то ваша программа является *некорректной* (ill-formed) с точки зрения С++. И при этом является корректной, но ведущей себя неопределенно с точки зрения С. (Последнее говорит о том, что ни о каком "работает в C" в данном случае не может быть и речи, какой бы вы смысл ни вкладывали в слово "работает".)

Также можно заметить, что допустимые проявления неопределенного поведения включают и отказ компилятора компилировать код, содержащий неопределенное поведение. То есть при желании компилятор языка С имеет полное право реагировать на этот код точно так же, как отреагировал в вашем случае компилятор языка С++.

---

И, вдогонку, удивляет сама постановка вопроса про "почему тот же самый код работает в C и не работает в C++". С и С++ - сильно разные языки. Поэтому не ясно почему тот факт, что "тот же самый код работает в C и не работает в C++", вызывает вопросы.

Comment: В стандарте языка сказано, что "A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type **large enough to hold it**". Однако, относительно преобразования целого в указательный тип сказано, что "A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer." Означает ли это, что **любое** целочисленное значение может быть преобразовано в некоторое указательное значение?

Comment: @wololo: Да, означает, в том смысле, что преобразование будет well-formed (т.е. "скомпилируется"). А что получится в результате за указатель языком определяется только для случая "кругового" преобразования "указатель -> целое -> указатель" с использованием целого достаточного размера: гарантируется, что будет восстановлено исходное значение указателя. В остальном поведение определяется реализацией и может быть неопределенным.

Comment: "В остальном поведение определяется реализацией и может быть **неопределенным**". Как же так? Ведь для случая "некругового" преобразования в стандарте сказано "mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined." Я думал, что могу конвертировать любое целое в указатель и в результате этот указатель примет некоторое указательное значение. Да, указатель может принять invalid pointer value, но неужели  "mappings [...] implementation-defined" означает также, что поведение программы может быть не определено?

Comment: @wololo: А в чем проблема? "Определяется реализацией" означает лишь то, что реализация имеет право сказать в том числе и то, что "поведение не определено". Аналогичный пример: при выполнении реинтерпретации памяти через `union` в С поведение *определяется реализацией*. Тем не менее при этом явно говорится, что такая реинтерпретация запросто может привести к формированию trap representation с неопределенным поведением. А с указателями вообще строго: работа с кривым указателем - всегда неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 6):

То что вы написали - это приведение типов. В общем тут вообще не понятно зачем этот код нужен? Дело в том, что неразыменованный указатель - это адрес ячейки памяти (8-ми байтовое число, как правило. Когда вы делаете (int) b - вы просто урезаете его до 4 байт. Подобное приведение типов в С++ не разрешено (в таком виде).